# Trying to control File-QMenu Actions in QT

Tags: c++, qt, action

iam trying to control an action on C++ of a QMenu in QT Creator. i have a window that has a label posting the action the user clicks from a menu to text but i want to control each sub menu seperately (the action of its).

Different function for "OPEN", different function for "QUIT" etc.

Any ideas?

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        setFixedSize(500,300);
        setWindowTitle("Menu Demo");
        mainWidget=new QWidget;
        setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
        mainWidget->setFixedSize(this->width(),this->height());
        mainLayout=new QVBoxLayout;
        mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

        mainLabel=new QLabel;
        mainLayout->addWidget(mainLabel);

         fileMenu= new QMenu("FILE");


         **fileMenu->addAction("SAVE"); //ACTIONS......different function.
         **fileMenu->addAction("SAVE AS");**
         **fileMenu->addAction("QUIT");****

         editMenu= new QMenu("EDIT");

         **editMenu->addAction("COPY");**
         **editMenu->addAction("CUT");**
         **editMenu->addAction("PASTE");**

         menuBar()->addMenu(fileMenu);
         menuBar()->addMenu(editMenu);
         connect(fileMenu,SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),this,SLOT(menuSlot(QAction*)));
         connect(editMenu,SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)),this,SLOT(menuSlot(QAction*)));
    }

    void MainWindow::menuSlot(QAction *action)
    {
        mainLabel->setText("ACTION: "+action->text());
    }
```

**Mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
# include <QVBoxLayout>
# include <QHBoxLayout>
# include <QLabel>
# include <QMenu>
# include <QMenuBar>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QWidget *mainWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout;
    QLabel *mainLabel;
    QMenuBar *menubar;
    QMenu *fileMenu;
    QMenu *editMenu;
public slots:
    void menuSlot(QAction *action);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: That's not C, that's C++.

Comment: And if you want to mark out specific line in the code you show, don't use markdown formatting, instead add *comments* in the code.

Comment: Your question is -- to me at least -- very unclear.  Can you clarify what you mean by "i want to control each sub menu seperately with some way i dont know".

Comment: @G.M The action of its. I want to do seperate function for "OPEN" clicked or the other sub menus.

Comment: as it is the void MainWindow::menuSlot(QAction *action). I want to do this for all the actions in the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test `action->text()` in `MainWindow::menuSlot` and perform the requested action...

```
void MainWindow::menuSlot (QAction *action)
{
    mainLabel->setText("ACTION: "+action->text());
    if (action->text() == "SAVE") {

        /*
         * Do whatever is required for `SAVE'.
         */
    } else if (action->text() == "SAVE AS") {

        /*
         * Do whatever is required for `SAVE AS'.
         */
    }
}
```

You just need to make sure the text associated with each `QAction` is unique.

Alternatively, you could have a slot for each action...

```
fileMenu= new QMenu("FILE");
auto *a = fileMenu->addAction("SAVE");
connect(a, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction *)), this, SLOT(save_slot(QAction *)));
a = fileMenu->addAction("SAVE AS");
connect(a, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction *)), this, SLOT(save_as_slot(QAction *)));
a = fileMenu->addAction("QUIT");
connect(a, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction *)), this, SLOT(quit_slot(QAction *)));
```

As a side note, if you're using Qt5 you should prefer the new [connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) for signals and slots.